# Rails Admin- Problemas com a gem paperclip e ckeditor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Integrei minha aplicação com o rails admin, e coloquei o ckeditor em um dos forms, segui todos os passos da [documentação oficial](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) mas ele não esta aceitando o meu config.js, eu reduzi a quantidade de opções por que não era necessário ter todas, mas ele está aparecendo o padrão (full). E também não está fazendo o upload de fotos, tentei pelo [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). Alguém tem ideia do porque isso está acontecendo, e como posso resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver. Depois de colocar as gems no Gemfile, e instalar, gerei o model do ckeditor, como está no tutorial. Para fazer ele pegar minhas configurações, coloquei no initializers/rails_admin.rb

```
field :campo, :ck_editor, :ckeditor => { :toolbar => 'mini'}
```

e também

```
field :campo, :ck_editor do config_js base_location + "page.js" end
```

coloquei no initializers/assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/* )
```